# How to include bottomTabs only on one screen

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

I'm trying to use react-native-navigation and have a question about it.

I have a list screen with a lot of items and when you click on one of them, it will bring you to a details screen and I need 3 bottomtabs on that screen.

What is the best way to achieve this with react native navigation.

I could do something like this( see code ). 
But then I’m stuck with the 3 bottomtabs on every screen.

```
Navigation.setRoot({
  root: {
    bottomTabs: {
      children: [{
        stack: {
          children: [{
            component: {
              name: 'SignIn',
              passProps: {
                text: 'ex tab'
              },
              options: {
                bottomTab: {
                  text: 'tab1',
                  icon: require('./images/one.png'),
                }
              }
            },
          }] // end children
        }  // end stack      
      },
      {
        component: {
          name: 'SignUp',
          passProps: {
            text: 'Sign up tab'
          },
          options: {
            bottomTab: {
              text: 'tab2',
              icon: require('./images/two.png'),
            }
          }
        },
      },
      {
        component: {
          name: 'SignUp',
          passProps: {
            text: 'Sign up tab'
          },
          options: {
            bottomTab: {
              text: 'tab2',
              icon: require('./images/two.png'),
            }
          }
        },


      }]

    } // end bottomtabs
  }
})
```

Any help or tips would be appreciated.

Comment: I can recommend `react-native-tabs` that works pretty well for this (https://github.com/aksonov/react-native-tabs)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but a tab is related to a different screen.

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty good practice with React-Navigation to put your Auth Stack in one branch of a switch navigator and then the rest of your app within another branch of a switch navigator within a Stack Navigator. That way if you want tabs on your auth stack it's technically it's own stack and won't bleed into the rest of your app.
For instance:

```
app
-AuthSwitch
   \_Tab1
   \_Tab2
   \_Tabn
-MainSwitch
  \_HomeStack
  \_etc...
```